# Count unique values in a set date range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm in need to count how many unique values (names) are in a column based on a date range (could be a single day or several days).

My data is stored as following.

Column A = Dates mm/dd/yy 
Column B = Names

Unfortunately, the way the data is imported into my file, does not give me any other option but to use names as a reference for unique employee identification, no IDs are listed.

The idea is to have a 2 cells, for "From" and "To" to enter the dates to perform the unique value calculations and to return the result to another cell.

I've made a sample of more or less what I'm looking for. You'll find a tab where I'd like to input the dates and a tab with a sample DB.

http://public.justcloud.com/e04wqfgc89.83937591

These unique values will allow me to perform additional calculations needed for a report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for Results!S2 should look like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((DB!$A$2:$A$262>=A2)*(DB!$A$2:$A$262<=B2))/(COUNTIFS(DB!$A$2:$A$262,">="&A2,DB!$A$2:$A$262,"<="&B2,DB!$B$2:$B$262,DB!$B$2:$B$262&"")+(DB!$A$2:$A$262<A2)+(DB!$A$2:$A$262>B2)))
```

I've seen worksheet designers use `MIN(A2:B2)` and `MAX(A2:B2)` to guard against the user putting the *Start* and *Stop* dates in the wrong order but I generally let users break things for themselves in they cannot distinguish between *Date From* and *Date To*.

Comment: Thank you. This works great. as a matter of fact now I'm in a bind, all 3 responses work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this "array formula" in C2

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF((DB!A$2:A$300>A2)*(DB!A$2:A$300<B2),MATCH(DB!B$2:B$300,DB!B$2:B$300,0)),ROW(DB!B$2:B$300)-ROW(DB!B$2)+1),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub test()
Dim oCell As Range, i&, LRow&: i = 1
Dim Group As Object: Set Group = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim DtFrom As Date, DtTo As Date
With Sheets("Results")
    DtFrom = .Cells(2, 1).Value
    DtTo = .Cells(2, 2).Value
End With
LRow = Sheets("DB").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For Each oCell In Sheets("DB").Range("A2:A" & LRow)
        If Not Group.exists(oCell.Offset(, 1).Value) And oCell.Value <> "" And _
        CDate(oCell.Value) >= DtFrom And CDate(oCell.Value) <= DtTo Then
            Group.Add oCell.Offset(, 1).Value, i: i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
Sheets("Results").Cells(2, 3).Value = Group.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as needed. right now I have the spreadsheet setup with formulas but as I continue to improve the report, I will most likely need to switch to the macro.